# Maven - erroneous weblogic classpath

Tags: maven, weblogic, classloader, pom.xml

On my Oracle weblogic 12 installation I have deployed an .ear (built with maven). All is OK except when I go to wls-cat and check Classloader Tree I get entries such as:

```
D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\liferayportal\servers\AdminServer\tmp\_WL_user\mywebapp\nsio4q\APP-INF\lib\lib\antlr-2.7.6.jar
```

and

```
D:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\liferayportal\servers\AdminServer\tmp\_WL_user\mywebapp\5ohvco\war\WEB-INF\lib\..\..\lib\
```

I have no \lib\lib folder and neither do \lib...\...\lib

What can be the cause? What should I check in my POMs? Thank you.

Comment: How did you deploy? Please add the relvant part(s) of your POM(s) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your pom.xml
WLS expands the war file, but copy the files in different places, therefor It doesn't recreate a directory structure (ie: OC4J does it).

Therefore, WLS-CAT is telling where (psychically) is retrieving a particular class (from antlr jar file in your case).